# Log when program is run

Tags: logs, monitoring, kiosk, cpu-usage

I am running a "kiosk" computer - one for general use for anybody in the room - and I want to know if anyone is actually using it.  Is there a log that tells me when firefox, chromium or other programs are run?

I am not asking for logs of what they are doing in the programs, just whether or not they are being used.

Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably should be interested by [process accounting](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/). See [acct(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/acct.2.html), [acct(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html), [sa(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sa.8.html)

Comment: I didn't use this suggestion, but since you were the only one who bothered to answer I marked as accepted.  Thanks for trying to help me out.